# Nest js install package

Tags: javascript, npm, package, npm-install, nest

I made a package for my project and I have installed it to my repository. However I can not import the functions from that package.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {  
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@qlub-dev/js-backend-common": ["./node_modules/@qlub-dev/js-backend-common"]
```

Answer (score 1):

npm ls @qlub-dev/js-backend-common
ab-qsr@1.0.0 /Users/qlub/Desktop/ab-qsr
└── @qlub-dev/js-backend-common@1.0.6

Comment: npm ls @qlub-dev/js-backend-common
ab-qsr@1.0.0 /Users/qlub/Desktop/ab-qsr
└── @qlub-dev/js-backend-common@1.0.6

Answer (score 0):

npm ls @qlub-dev/js-backend-common

Comment: npm ls @qlub-dev/js-backend-common
ab-qsr@1.0.0 /Users/qlub/Desktop/ab-qsr
└── @qlub-dev/js-backend-common@1.0.6

Comment: you should be able to import functions from it in your TypeScript code as follows: 
 import { someFunction } from '@qlub-dev/js-backend-common';

Comment: Now I solved the issue but I have node modules error node_modules/@qlub-dev/js-backend-common/user/user.service.ts:39:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/interface/brand/brand' or its corresponding type declarations.